# a-frame upload images in glitch

Tags: html, image-uploading, aframe

I'm having trouble figuring out how make my html code in glitch functional. Currently the project that this code is addressing is creating a web space that allows the upload of 360 images and allows the user to view the image once its been submitted. The two problems are a functional upload button for 360 images in glitch. This is my current code for it:

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
  $errors= array();
  $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
  $file_size =$_FILES['image']['size'];
  $file_tmp =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
  $file_type=$_FILES['image']['type'];
  $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));

  $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");

  if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
     $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
  }

  if($file_size > 2097152){
     $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
  }

  if(empty($errors)==true){
     move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/".$file_name);
     echo "Success";
  }else{
     print_r($errors);
  }
}
?>

<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" name="image" />
     <input type="submit"/>
  </form>
```

The other problem is taking the uploaded 360 image and opening a new tab that allows you to view the 360 image using glitch and A-frame. I have code for this because I'm not able to figure it out. Would love to get some feedback on my problem, the upload button being the priority. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Glitch doesn't support PHP out of the box (unlike node) so you might look at https://support.glitch.com/t/is-there-is-php-on-glitch/2503 for solutions.